# Structure of a simple PHP quiz with multiple pages

Tags: php, forms

I'm trying to make a simple quiz app with the following structure:

- 10 questions, every question is on a new html page.
   It looks a bit like: http://howmuchtomakeanapp.com/ structurewise
- Every answer in a question is a form that gets submitted that looks like this (so if there are 3 answers, they all are embedded with their own unique form):

  ```
  <form method="post" action="../question2/">
     <button type="submit" class="icon-button">
         <img src="../../img/placeholder.png">
     </button>
     <input type="hidden" name="question" value="question1">                               
     <input type="hidden" name="answer" value="Q1A">                
  </form>
  ```
- I have an array with values in PHP, and answers will be connected to these values. For example: answer Q1A is worth 5 points, Q1B will be worth 3.

  ```
  $var = [
     "Q1A" => 5,
     "Q1B" => 3,
     "Q1C" => 0,
     "Q2A" => 2,
     "Q2B" => 3,
      ...
  ];
  ```

I have one PHP file at the moment (calculate.php) which I want to calculate the total of points in. This is where I am stuck. I'm not really sure how to save my answers and thus connecting their values. I'm not sure how I should structure it.

*My question*: What is my best way of working to save these values, and in the end get a total of points to show the user. I can't get a clear view on how I should do my server-side communication. How should my calculate.php look like?

Comment: are you interested in making this only PHP? js would be suitable

Comment: I am trying to keep the values of my answers hidden in PHP. So I prefer just trying it in PHP aswell. It would also be a good learning for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've have solved this by using sessions.

```
    session_start();
    if(isset($_POST['answer'])){
    $_SESSION['question1'] = $_POST['answer'];}
```

For every page I have added a new session variable. I ended up counting the score in the last page by connecting answers to the array of the score.

Answer (score 0):

If i get your question, you could save your values in a php variable then POSt it from page to page